# A conjecture of Thurston and possibly Weeks too

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry, gt.geometric-topology, mg.metric-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, 3-manifolds

What is the status of the following conjecture:

> "... [w]hen the shortest simple closed geodesics are repeatedly removed from any complete hyperbolic 3-manifold of finite volume, eventually one obtains a manifold whose shortest closed geodesic has length $2.12255\ldots$ with angle of twist $\pm 1.80911 \ldots,$ and has self-replicating behaviour when removed."

This is Conjecture 6.1 from p. 2568 of Thurston's expository paper "How to see 3-manifolds" (Class. Quantum Grav. **15** (1998) 2545--2571).

Comment: I think this is still open. 

Comment: Adams' paper on simple geodesics has a heuristic explanation of why this might be happening.